# How can you check the installed Certificate Authority in windows 7/8?

Tags: certificate-authority

And know which are not default ones installed by Microsoft?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To view your certificate stores, run `certmgr.msc` as described [there](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/view-or-manage-your-certificates). The "root" store contains the root CA, i.e. the CA which are trusted *a priori*. `certmgr.msc` shows you an aggregate view of all root CA which apply to the current user; internally, there are several relevant stores (the "local machine" stores apply to all users, the "current user" stores are specific to the current user; and there also are "enterprise" stores which are similar to "local machine" but meant to be filled automatically from the AD server of the current domain).

See [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125) for a list of all CA that Microsoft puts in Windows by default; any discrepancy would be a local variation. The list is occasionally updated, and this is propagated to your computer through the normal Windows update mechanisms.

Comment: Followed instructions, and see the lists of certificates in differrent folders, but the top level is "Certificate - Current User" and I did not find the "local machine" foder/node. Is this access right issue?I am the admin of the PC though.

Comment: `certmgr.msc` shows an aggregate view -- i.e. what impacts the current user, and that's a merge of his "current user stores" and the "local machine stores". To view stores separately, use `mmc.exe` with the "certificate viewer" snap-in, which will give you that option.

Comment: Be nice if there were a tool to automatically check the CA certificates are standard or not.

Comment: For anyone looking to add certs into the root CA, right-click "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" >> "All Tasks" >> "Import".

Comment: @Petah There is one: [`sigcheck`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441), it is part of the Sysinternals Suite. If you run it from the `cmd` with `sigcheck -tv`, it does exactly that...

Answer (score 21):

There is a Microsoft Sysinternals utility that does just that: [SigCheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx)

It has many features and options but what you want is:

```
sigcheck -tv
```

and

```
sigcheck -tuv
```

> -t[u][v]  Dump contents of specified certificate store ('*' for all stores).  Specify -tu to query the user store (machine store is the
>   default).  **Append '-v' to have Sigcheck download the trusted Microsoft
>   root certificate list and only output valid certificates not rooted to
>   a certificate on that list. If the site is not accessible,
>   authrootstl.cab or authroot.stl in the current directory are used
>   instead, if present.**

Comment: related: CertWatch essentially runs sigcheck -tu every hour and alerts you of any changes

http://www.blaser.us/software/certwatch/

Answer (score 1):

There is an utility called **RCC** that checks Windows certificate authority storage and compares it to Microsoft Root Certificate Program list. Firefox certificate storage is also supported. But its authors are unknown and source code isn't published to date.
[Discussion.](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/rcc-check-your-systems-trusted-root-certificate-store.373819/)