# I logged into my work computer with my personal email, can my employer see my google search history on Chrome?

Tags: privacy, chrome

Stupid mistake here. Today at home using my work computer I logged into my gmail on Chrome to check my personal email. I then went to look something up in google and saw several google search suggestions that I only typed in on my home computer; I don't have sync on, but I guess google searches are shared between devices if you're logged in on the same google account.

Is there any way for my work to see my google search history. I double checked and it doesn't seem websites or anything are shared, it's just that in Chrome google autofills certain searches whenever I type.

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate of [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/142803/2138) but rather a question about how Chrome, Google search and Google login interacts. As such, it might possibly be better off asked on [su].

Comment: The answer depends on what software is running on the computer and what they are monitoring. Of course they could have the capability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your network setup. My company laptop requires me to connect to cooperate VPN before I can access the public internet from home or on-the-go. In this case, all my traffic is routed to the cooperate network before it breaks out to the public internet. By doing so, the company is able to enforce security policies and controls. If I were to browse the public internet, my company proxy server will log all my activities.

Some companies simply allow direct internet access from their laptops while off the cooperate network. In that case, its not easy to enforce security polices to remote users. Therefore its not easy to track user activity.

Some companies install security agents on laptops to monitor user activities. [CrowdStrike](https://www.crowdstrike.com/) is a good example. It monitors processes and files being executed on local machine (laptop), and then reports back to the cooperate network on-the-fly.