# What difference to privacy will I get if i change my workplace wifi DNS to static ones on my iPad?

Tags: dns, ios

I access internet at my workplace with an iPad that has workplace profile installed on it. This allows me to automatically connect to the company wifi, along with their own DNS settings. If I change these settings to a static address, would I be able to have a bit more privacy when I access the web, or will all my activity still be monitored by the company?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/can-my-employer-see-what-i-do-on-the-internet-when-i-am-connected-to-the-company)

Answer (score 0):

DNS just resolves the urls to ip adresses, If your workplace have a proxy on a gateway and encrypts\decrypts client requests with it's own certificate, then they will be able to monitor all your traffic. That is said, this is not a usual approach, since it would require a significant amount of money to install and maintain storage for all these logs. It is generally not a good idea to use internet access for a private means on any environment that may have require an installation of it's own certificates.

Answer (score 0):

DNS resolves URLs into IP addresses. For instance, if you want to visit www.microsoft.com, your iPad would first ask the DNS server for the IP address and then connect to that IP address. Change DNS server (if it is allowed by your company) will only make your company unable to see what URLs you were attempting to resolve, but since all the HTTP traffic still toes through your company's network, it can still see what IP address you try to connect. So you won't expect much more privacy by changing the setting.