# Can an employer see all of your local network activity or just the device connected to their VPN?

Tags: privacy, vpn

I own the home internet router, and during work hours, I connect to my company’s VPN.

I have recently been on the radar with my HR and management. So I feel I am being tracked closely by them.

When I am connected to the company’s VPN and the same wifi is used on my other personal devices, can my company track my internet history of other devices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my employer monitor personal device use on my home network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/218733/can-my-employer-monitor-personal-device-use-on-my-home-network), [Can my employer see what websites I visit at home on my personal devices?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229048/can-my-employer-see-what-websites-i-visit-at-home-on-my-personal-devices)