# Can my school monitor what I do on my personal device?

Tags: tracking

So, I was just at home, minding my business. I was on some sites that are not allowed at school, and my email was logged in.
I was using safari with the google site.

Do they know what I am doing now? They openly say they monitor everything we do on our school laptops.

Comment: Was this your school laptop?

Comment: Duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/can-my-employer-see-what-i-do-on-the-internet-when-i-am-connected-to-the-company/142928

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that the admins of a machine can do pretty much anything they want on that machine.

So it is perfectly possible to install loggers that track any site accessed from that machine, and it is easy to do that. It could even be possible to log the full activity (including actions on locally installed programs), but this is only used for very sensitive laptops to make sure that an attacker has not accessed them.

Anyway this will learn you one of the basic security rules: if someone else has control over your device, it is not **your** device. So you should not use it for something that they forbid.